# Multiple DeclareSourcemap rules

Tags: biblatex, biber

I don't think I understand how the `\DeclareSourcemap` works in `biblatex`.

I'm trying to define 3 rules:

1. Move `issue` to number;
2. Remove `number` for journals that start with "Phys. Rev.";
3. Remove `volume` for journals that are "JHEP".

Here's what I have right now, but it seems to apply all transformations to all bibliography entries.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=issue]
      \step[fieldset=number, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=issue, null]
      %
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, match=\regexp{\APhys\.\s+Rev\.}]
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
      %
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, match=\regexp{\AJHEP\Z}]
      \step[fieldset=volume, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I would also like for `issue` to be moved to `number` **only if** `number` is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biber processes all `\step`s in a `\map` sequentially unless one of the `\step`s has the `final` option, which tells Biber to stop at this step if it does not apply.

Since there are no `final`s in the code shown in the question, all `\step`s get executed, which means that in the end both `volume` and `number` get removed.

You need to separate the different things you want to do into separate `\map`s and use `final`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    % remap fields for all entries, but nothing will be overwritten
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=issue,   fieldtarget=number]
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    }
    % delete number only for Phys. Rev.
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, match=\regexp{\APhys\.\s+Rev\.}, final]
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
    % delte volume only for JHEP
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, match=\regexp{\AJHEP\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=volume, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev.},
  volume    = {131},
  issue     = {5},
}
@article{belk,
  author    = {Anne Belk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1971},
  journal   = {JHEP},
  volume    = {132},
  issue     = {6},
}
@article{celk,
  author    = {Anne Celk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1974},
  journal   = {Lorem},
  volume    = {133},
  issue     = {7},
}
@article{delk,
  author    = {Anne Delk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1975},
  journal   = {Lorem},
  volume    = {134},
  number    = {8},
}
@article{felk,
  author    = {Anne Felk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1977},
  journal   = {Lorem},
  volume    = {135},
  number    = {9},
  issue     = {Michaelmas term},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk,belk,celk,delk,felk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Belk, Anne (1971). ‘A Theory on Brontosauruses’. In: JHEP 6.]